# PowerQuery to get data from web table to excel/powerbi, selecting rows

Tags: excel, web, powerquery

I am trying to get data from a web table. The website has a table where we can select the number of rows (10, 50 100). By detault this number is 10

When i  try to get data using powerquery, i can only get the first 10 rows. How do i modify the query to get 100 rows instead.

I tried advanced query, but cant seem to find any option that allows me to select the number of rows.

Comment: You didn't provide any sample code but likely would be similar to https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.